# Change style for the reply link in comment.tpl.php

Tags: comments, navigation

How could I style the "reply" link in comment.tpl.php?

I have this line of code inside:

```
<?php print render($content['links']) ?>
```

With this I get something like the following:

```
<ul class="links inline" thmr="thmr_249"><li class="comment-reply first last"><a href="/?q=comment/reply/28/1" thmr="thmr_250 thmr_251">reply</a></li></ul>
```

I manage to get the exact URL with `<?php print render($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']['href']) ?>`, but for some reason it doesn't work perfectly: It loses the "/?q=" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
<?php print url($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']['href']); ?>
```

If you pass node/1 to `url()`, it will  return /?q=node/1 when clean URLs are not enabled, and /node/1 when clean URL are enabled.